# Function without any digital help.

Tags: functions

Ive come into some trouble answering this function:

$$h(x)=-0.05(x^2)+x+2.20 $$

$x$ and $h(x)$ are both shown in meters.

I need to solve this function with $h(0)$.

would be nice is someone could explain me this, because im not that good in maths. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean: "Given $h(x)=-.05^2+x+2.2$, compute $h(0)$."  ?  If so...where do you get stuck when you substitute $0$ for $x$?

Comment: That function is written a bit strangely...is it possible you meant to write $h(x)=-.05x^2+x+2.2?

Comment: my book shows that the correct answer is 2.20, i cant manage to get it

Comment: Yes...I expect that you intended my version of your function (quadratic in $x$).  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just solving for $h(0)$ then you would do as follows:

$$h(0) = -0.05(0^2) + (0) + 2.20 = ....$$

I think you should be able to figure the rest!

Comment: ah yes... forgot to put zeroes in brackets, thanks mate